# Conditional regex replace if value less than "nnnn"

Tags: .net, regex

Not sure if this is possible with a regular expression replace command, but I have an existing regex replace which will convert the last two digits of a number to the same last two digits prefixed with a full stop.  This is for interfacing to a system which sends through currency values as "2500" where this represents "25.00" dollars.

My existing regex: `(\d+)(\d{2})$`
With replace syntax of: `$1.$2`

Now I have a problem though, if a value is sent through as "50" only for example, this could represent 0.50 and my regex will fail because it is searching for 1+ numeric on the left, and two numeric exactly at the end of the string.

How could I cover all these circumstances and have my regex replace replace thusly:

```
2500 = 25.00
500 = 5.00
50 = 0.50
5 = 0.05
```

Thanks again,
Graham

**Update: For those asking why this cannot be a divide and string format job is because I have to avoid custom programming to achieve this.  It must ideally be a regex "rule" defined in a database along with other regex definitions as it's being used for a generic translation system.  It will translate incoming data which could come in multiple format types, generally translating a field from "101" to "101A" for example, but in this particular case for this data type, adding values is required.**

**Second update: I've been thinking more about this, because I am bound to a database, would anybody see a better way than using a %wackyMoney% or some other 'token' defined in the db field and then test if we hit this token in code to apply the C# string formatting and divide?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you using a regexp for this?! There isn't going to be an easy way to do that with a *single* regexp, but you could do it with several (one for the 3+ digit case, one for the 2-digit case, one for the 1-digit case). But...

I don't know the exact C# syntax, but something along the lines of:

```
sprintf('%0.2f', «var»/100.0)
```

would seem to do exactly what you want as long as your numbers are small enough that your floating-point type is precise to better than 0.01. For doubles, that is well into the quadrillions.

## edit 1

Since you need regexps, you can use three (in Perl syntax here, but...):

```
s/^(\d+)(\d{2})$/$1.$2/;   # you already have this
s/^(\d{2})$/0.$1/;         # obvious variant 1
s/^(\d{1}$/0.0$1/;         # obvious variant 2
```

Only one of those will match (variant 1 requires 3+ chars, variant 2 exactly 2 chars, variant 3 exactly 1 char), so you can use this if you can attach multiple regexps. I could get all that into one regexp in Perl, but I have no idea if you have full Perl regexp features (I doubt it). After all, Perl could do:

```
s/^(\d+)$/sprintf('%0.2f', $1/100.0)/e
```

but that's rather cheating. Does your regexp engine have anything similar? Or you said this is a database thing; can you use SQL's `CASE` conditional?

Comment: A regex is being used because this is for a generic translation system and the translation rule is being defined in the database for a set of incoming data, odd I know, in a normal circustance.  But this isn't normal :)

Comment: Wow, great response. I'm using the .NET regex engine, and I don't think we could call commands in regex like that though! Would be nice. I think however you could be definitely on to something with the semi-colon delimited regex set, I definitely have the power to be able to change the regex parser to parse multiple regex set's by semi-colon if I can't do multi-line out of the box, will take a look - thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad to hear I've been of help.

Answer (score 3):

.Net regexes can use a match evaluator to transform the match to whatever is desired:

```
String result = Regex.Replace(
   "test 1 test 20 test 300 test 4000 test 50000",
   @"\d+",
   (match => (Double.Parse(match.Value) / 100).ToString("0.00")));
```

The result is:

```
test 0.01 test 0.20 test 3.00 test 40.00 test 500.00
```

Comment: This answer put me in the right direction.  My goal was to fix any poorly formatted dates that should start with the month, but occasionally would start with the day.  My method needed to swap the month and day only when the month is > 12.

Answer (score 2):

Regular expressions can't create content that doesn't exist, so you can't add a zero that isn't there. So the answer is that you shouldn't use regular expressions for this.

Your best bet would be to use `(Double.Parse(value) / 100).ToString("0.00")` or some such.

---

Since you want a generic ruleset defined in the database, I think the error here is that you're mixing numeric rules with string rules. You should probably make your database support different types of rules.

I think you should have an additional column specifying whether the value should be modified numerically or as a string. If it should be modified numerically, you could have the column currently used for the replacement specify a multiplier or some such.

If you want to take it even further, you could have a simple formula evaluator that could take something like: `x / 100 + " USD"`. There are plenty of these available for .NET already, and it isn't very hard to make a simple one yourself either.

Comment: I thought this was the case exactly, the content must exist first. I'll have a think, but as I responded to derobert's message, it has to be a generic, un-programmed db-defined handler ideally.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a reason for not converting the string to a number, divide by 100, and convert back to a string with appropriate fomatting?

Answer (score 0):

This may not answer the op's question exactly, but it could give you some ideas on how to take advantage of match parameters based on a condition.

The below method will swap the Day and Month portions of a date if the month is > 12.
Example:

```
string myStr = "14/3/2018";
string newStr = MDYToDMY(myStr);
Console.WriteLine(newStr); // prints "3/14/2018"

    static string MDYToDMY(string input)
    {
        try
        {
            return Regex.Replace(input,
                "\\b(?<month>\\d{1,2})/(?<day>\\d{1,2})/(?<year>\\d{2,4})\\b",
                (match => (int.Parse(match.Groups["month"].Value) > 12) 
                    ? $"{match.Groups["day"]}/{match.Groups["month"]}/{match.Groups["year"]}" 
                    : $"{match.Groups["month"]}/{match.Groups["day"]}/{match.Groups["year"]}"),
                RegexOptions.None,
                TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(150));
        }
        catch (RegexMatchTimeoutException)
        {
            return input;
        }
    }
```